# Excel VBA: How to record user key press in a change event after application.undo?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using `Application.Undo` in my Change Event to record the previous value of the changed cell and re-assign that cell with the new value.

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    vNew = Target.Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Undo
    vOld = Target.Value
    Target.Value = vNew
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Because of that assignment, the active cell is always that target cell and the last key pressed by the user to go to the next cell (Enter or Right Arrow) needs to used twice to actually go to the next cell.

Is there a way to maybe record that key press so I can force it in the code?

The user is required to change multiple cells in consecutive rows/columns, making this a tiny bit annoying.

Comment: You want the onkey event to trigger a macro? Have you looked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey)?

Comment: I already tried using ````Application.OnKey```` after the last line of the above code. But it doesn't detect the key press so it never goes into the procedure that manually forces an Enter.

Comment: You want to initialize these under workbook.open, or worksheet.activate or some other way to have these ready to call your procedure once a key is pressed. Not in the last line of the actual procedure it needs to call. Or am I reading your question wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the change event can be triggered in at least 7 different ways:

1. the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
2. the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key
3. the four ARROW keys
4. a paste operation

There is no easy way *(without a keyboard API)* to capture which one the user used.  I suggest that YOU take control and force the issue:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        vNew = Target.Value
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        vOld = Target.Value
        Target.Value = vNew
        Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done the same thing with ````SendKeys "{ENTER}"```` but I guess i can use this too. I just wanted to know if there actually was a way to capture what the user pressed but I see your point and will have to make do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Without application.undo and .onkey:

```
Public vOld As Variant 'these 2 in a module
Public vOld2 As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    vOld2 = vOld
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    vOld = Target.Value
End Sub
```